# If cell in Column K returns FALSE, clear cell in Column B

Tags: excel, vba

I have a file where the user will be entering information in Column B, the Location SKU.

Column K will display if the user has entered the correct information in column B by displaying either True or False.

What I am trying to accomplish is if column K returns False, the information in column B will be cleared, become the active cell, and the user will need to enter the correct information to return a True value.

The code I have below is confined to cell B2.

Would anyone be able to help, please?

Thank you so much!

Picture of what I am hoping to accomplish: https://i.stack.imgur.com/5uzp1.jpg

`Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Excel.Range)
   Dim cell22 As Range, b As Boolean
      Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each cell22 In Target
         If Not Application.Intersect(cell22, Range("k2:k6000")) Is Nothing Then
          If cell22.Value <> True Then
            Range("B2").ClearContents
            Range("B2").Activate
            b = True
         End If
     End If
    Next cell22
    If b Then MsgBox "xxx", vbInformation, 
    "Important:"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End sub`

Comment: As a user I would find that very frustrating - what if I made a small typo?  you clear it out and I start from scratch...   Would help your question if you mention how this is being called - in the sheet "change" event?

Comment: Thanks for your response! I completely understand. The user is not manually entering in information; rather, they are using a barcode scanner to scan SKUs. In this case, I am trying to ensure they are returning items to the correct place by scanning the Shelf SKU. If they are returning the item to the incorrect shelf, cell K will return a FALSE value and also a message box is populated to let the user know they are returning the item to the incorrect shelf. That is why I need cell B to be cleared, so they can scan the correct Shelf SKU and have Column K return a TRUE value.

Comment: Also, this is being called in the sheet change event, correct! My apologies for not stating this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range, hadProblem As Boolean

    'only check cells in ColB
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Me.Range("B:B"), Target)
    DoEvents 'allow for calculations

    On Error GoTo haveError

    If Not rng Is Nothing Then
        For Each c In rng.Cells
            'check "K" value
            If Not c.EntireRow.Cells(1, "K").Value Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                c.ClearContents
                Application.EnableEvents = True
                c.Select
                hadProblem = True
            End If
        Next c
    End If

    If hadProblem Then
        MsgBox "One or more cells in Column B had incorrect locations. Please rescan.", _
                vbExclamation, "Location Error"
    End If

    Exit Sub

haveError:
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'make sure events are turned back on

End Sub
```

Comment: This is perfect and exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much, Tim!